Non-invertible symmetries: Half gauging and 't Hooft lines
In (2.27) of https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.05086, when performing a gauge transformation of the background gauge field $B \to B +d \Lambda $, the 't Hooft line $H(\gamma)$ transforms as
\begin{equation}
H(\gamma) \to H(\gamma) \ e^{i \oint_\gamma \Lambda}.
\end{equation}
However, when gauging the $\mathbb{Z}_N^{(1)}$ 1-form magnetic symmetry, it is said that the 't Hooft line is not invariant anymore and, instead, it has to be replaced by the gauge invariant quantity
\begin{equation}
H(\gamma) \ \exp\left(-i \int_\Sigma b\right) \ ,
\end{equation}
where $b$ is a dynamical field which is coupled to $F$ in the action (2.18), which is
\begin{equation}
L_{\text{QED}} +\frac{i}{2\pi} b\wedge F+\frac{iN}{2\pi} b\wedge dc+\frac{iNk}{4\pi} b\wedge b \ .
\end{equation}
My question is the following. In order for this action to be gauge invariant, the gauge transformation of the field $A$ remains untouched, whereas the other transformations are
\begin{equation}
b\to b+ d\Lambda \ ,
\qquad
c\to c+d\Lambda^{(0)} - k \Lambda \ , 
\end{equation}
according to, for example, eqs. (B.6) and/or (B.10).
Then, if the gauge transformation of $A$ remains untouched,
(a)why does the field $A$ suffer the gauge transformation of $B$ and consequently,
(b)why do I have to redefine the gauge invariant quantity $H(\gamma)e^{-i\int b}$?
(c) what's the physical meaning of gauging $c$ instead of $A$? In the usual case of invertible transformations, it is the gauge field $A$ the one that cancels the gauge transformation of $b$ (see, for example, (A.6) in https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.04499)
